# Валидация доступа к файлу

Tags: php

Вот у DLE есть функция:

```
if dle else die(not dle, fuck off)
```

Как это работает?

И допустим, как сделать валидацию администратора? `$_SESSION['logged'] == 'admin'` очень небезопасно!

Я думаю сделать валидацию ключа (пара логин пароль совпала -> генерируем уникальный ключ -> заносим в бд ключ -> указываем в бд сколько живёт ключ, потом вычищаем из таблицы в бд данный ключ и шлём на страницу логина), но как это будет на практике?

Надёжно, или не очень?

Comment: `$_SESSION['logged'] == 'admin' очень небезопасно!`, не безопасно чем же?

Answer (score 0):

Валидировать можно смело сессиями, а если сомневаетесь в плане безопасности можно заземлять пару логин-пароль, например с солью, и к тому же время жизни сессии задавать можно, и без лишних запросов к баз е будет

Answer (score -1):

Могу быть не совсем точен, но делается это так:

```
<?php
define('DLE', TRUE);

if (DLE) { echo 'OK'; } else { echo 'NOT'; };
```

`define` — Определяет именованную константу (из документации). Т.е. грубо говоря `DLE` заменяется на `TRUE`. Прописан этот `define` скорее всего в `index.php` (но это не точно). Ну а дальше уже логично все. А такая запись как у вас это скорее всего какой-то упрощенный стиль `if`. Делается это для того, чтобы текущий скрипт (где прописано данное условие) мог запуститься только из среды `DLE` (это грубо говоря и не вдаваясь в подробности).